# Looking for a Geometry Book with Exercises (Not a Text Book)

Tags: euclidean-geometry

I am looking for a Geometry Book with Hard Exercises based on Euclidean Geometry that are covering topics such as Congruence, Parallelogram, Circles, Similarity, Simson Line etc... I am currently working on the [Challenging Problems in Geometry](https://g.co/kgs/vCmE9W) Book. I am looking for books that are like an alternative to that book. If anyone can please tell me a book that I can use for my purpose

Comment: I guess you can search for some books about geometry problems in Olympic math such as IMO. As I can remember, Euclidean geometry is often involved in those contests.

Comment: EGMO by Evan Chen is the holy bible of Euclidean geometry for olympiads, if you haven't looked at it yet.

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Geometry/Resources